# VBA wants strange "=" after replace function in If statement

Tags: excel, vba

Why does it want "=" sign after replace function?

```
For Each cel In Application.Selection.Cells
    scell = cel.Value
    For c = 1 To Len(scell)
        If Not is_number(Mid(scell, c, 1), c) Then
        Replace(scell, Mid(scell, c, 1),"")
        End If
               
    Next
Next
```

Comment: `Replace` is a function - it returns a string. You have to assign it to a variable or something. `x = Replace()` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you so much

Comment: There are better ways to extract just the numeric portion of a string, e.g. regex.

Comment: And this method will not work with back to back characters.  For example `1ab2cd` will return `1b2d` because the b which is in the 3rd place will become the 2nd when a is removed.  If you insist on using this method, loop backwards.

Comment: I'm doing it for practice, to learn loops, if statements, functions and so on